# Is there a way in R using the dplyr package to sample an equal number of factors?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
    > testing
# A tibble: 27,507 x 2
   type      mmr
   <fct>   <dbl>
 1 Public    100
 2 Public    100
 3 Private   100
 4 Public    100
 5 Public    100
 6 Public    100
 7 Public    100
 8 Public    100
 9 Public    100
10 Public    100
# ... with 27,497 more rows
```

This dataframe has the following count:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  type        n
  <fct>   <int>
1 Private  6815
2 Public  20692
```

I want to spread Public and Private into variables however these will need to have an equal count to do so. Is there a way to take a sample of 6000 private and 6000 public using the DPLYR package so I can perform the spread function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sample_n` :

```
library(dplyr)

data <- testing %>% group_by(type) %>% sample_n(6000)
```

Note that `spread` has been replaced with `pivot_wider` so to get data in wide format, you can then use

```
data %>% 
   group_by(a) %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%  
   tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = a, values_from = b) %>%
   #tidyr::spread(a, b) %>%
   select(-row)
```